# Find a word in string with known character position

Tags: python

My problem seems common but i cant find a solution for my case. I want to find a word in a string, using a known index of one of the letters creating said word. For example

```
'Pizza with extra toppings'.reverse_find(8)
#returns 'with'
```

I cant find a neat solution. Only thing that comes to my mind is to search for whitespace to the left and right of the String.

Comment: You mean, "find the word that includes the character at index X"?

Comment: The index is the first char of the word you want to find?

Comment: I think that would make things easier.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: It does, but somehow it returns the last word without last letter, and i get extra topping instead of toppings

Comment: This should work now I edited it. If it works for you, You can click the V to mark the answer as helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_word_by_index(word, index):
        while (word[index - 1] != " " and index > 0):
            index -= 1

        word = word[index:]

        if word.find(" ") == -1:
            return word

        word = word[:word.find(" ")]
        return word
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `index` and `rindex` with appropriate `start` and `end` parameters to search for the next and previous space, but this will be problematic with e.g. punctuation.

Instead, I'd suggest using `re.finditer` to find and iterate words in the string and compare the bounds of the match to your index.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Pizza with extra toppings'
>>> i = 8
>>> next(m.group() for m in re.finditer(r"\w+", text) if m.start() <= i < m.end())
'with'
```